# TypeError: '(slice(1, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key. Trying to convert a numpy array to dataframe using the indices of a other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this numpy array after perform MinMax Scaling:

```
dftransformed = scaler.transform(df1)
dftransformed

array([[0.70186067, 0.63422294, 0.60840393, ..., 0.57706373, 0.67144751,
        0.57292072],
       [0.70976009, 0.75551699, 0.55909346, ..., 0.73020882, 0.71565513,
        0.76358491],
       [0.54763595, 0.58429507, 0.66676546, ..., 0.53096619, 0.587302  ,
        0.66410096],
       ...,
       [0.58223568, 0.20418524, 0.34276947, ..., 0.59893092, 0.38758242,
        0.12860918],
       [0.11992947, 0.19754072, 0.19837881, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.01558628, 0.03226724, 0.09110852, ..., 0.01744946, 0.        ,
        0.        ]])
```

This operation erased the indices of the last dataframe, This is my last Dataframe:

[image]

Now I am trying to convert this numpy array to pandas Data Frame and add the indices I tried to this.

```
dftransformedtoDF = pd.DataFrame( dftransformed = dftransformed[1:,1:], index = df1[1:,0], columns = df1[0,1:]) 
# dftransformed is the numpy array, df1 is my dataframe
```

But I receive this output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-6331ce1c5564> in <module>
----> 1 dftransformedtoDF = pd.DataFrame( dftransformed = dftransformed[1:,1:], index = df1[1:,0], columns = df1[0,1:])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
   2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(1, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

I think maybe my problem here is the index is a dataframe and columns are dataframe. and pandas have problem with deal with that but What other option have I? convert the index, column dataframe to numpy and then add to the Dataframe Function?

Comment: `df1[1:,0]` is valid indexing for a 2d numpy array.  dataframes are 2d, but require some sort of `loc` expression to select both column and row.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `dftransformedtoDF = pd.DataFrame(dftransformed, index = df1.index, columns = df1.columns)` ?

Comment: The solution of @Riley work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new dataframe using previous dataframe index and columns using

```py
dftransformedtoDF = pd.DataFrame(dftransformed, index = df1.index, columns = df1.columns)
```